# Invalid character in file

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am using the free edition of Visual Studio 2019.  I created a blank project, then added dependencies for .masm(.targets, .props).  However, I am getting an error and not sure if it is my Visual Studio setup, or something else.

I am taking an assembler class and need to modify an example in our book to do more,  but first I wanted the original code to work.  As such, I typed in the code from the book but getting tons of errors about io.h and I am not sure what to do about it.  I am hoping someone can point out what what I am doing wrong.  I found one article on Google that addresses this, but didn't solve the issue and another suggested C++ comments in the io.h are the problem, but I cannot seem to remove them and save the file back.

Here is my code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h        ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
number1 DWORD   ?
number2 DWORD   ?
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter First Number", 0
prompt2 BYTE    "Enter Second Number", 0
string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)
resultLb1 BYTE "The Sum Is", 0
sum     BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
    input   prompt1, string, 40     ; read ASCII Characters
    atod    string                  ; convert to integer
    mov     number1, eax            ; store in memory

    input   prompt2, string, 40
    atod    string
    mov     number2, eax

    mov     eax, number1
    add     eax, number2
    dtoa    sum, eax
    output  resultLb1, sum

    mov     eax, 0
    ret
_MainProc ENDP
END                 ; end of source code
```

ERRORS:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: CYBR215, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Assembling Week_4_Code.asm...
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(1): error A2008: syntax error : /
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(2): error A2008: syntax error : /
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(3): error A2008: syntax error : /
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(4): error A2008: syntax error : /
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(5): error A2008: syntax error : /
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(6): error A2008: syntax error : /
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(7): error A2008: syntax error : /
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(8): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(9): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(10): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(11): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(12): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(13): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(14): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(15): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(16): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(17): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(18): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(19): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(20): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(21): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(22): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(23): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(24): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(25): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(26): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(27): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(28): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(29): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(30): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(31): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(32): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(33): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(34): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(35): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(36): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(37): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(38): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(39): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(40): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(41): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(42): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(43): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(44): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(45): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(46): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(47): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(48): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(49): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(50): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(51): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(52): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(53): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(54): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(55): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(56): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(57): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(58): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(59): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(60): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(61): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(62): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(63): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(64): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(65): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(66): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(67): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(68): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(69): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(70): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(71): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(72): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(73): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(74): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(75): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(76): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(77): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(78): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(79): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(80): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(81): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(82): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(83): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(84): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(85): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(86): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(87): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(88): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(89): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(90): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(91): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(92): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(93): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(94): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(95): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(96): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(97): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(98): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(99): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(100): error A2044: invalid character in file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\io.h(101): fatal error A1012: error count exceeds 100; stopping assembly
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(70,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Week_4_Code.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaWeek_4_Code.asm" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "CYBR215.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Looks like your build is picking up a wrong `io.h`, one that is for C not asm.

Comment: The given code seems to be somewhat ok. All the errors you are presenting are from `io.h` - which is **not** part of the question and hence, not possible to debug.

Comment: You cannot include **C** header files in ASM code. To do this, you need the [Windows MASM include files from Hutch](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?board=9.0).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  that does make sense about the C include not being asm, but unfortunately I cannot seem to download the MASM files from Hutch.  Neither US Site works for me.  Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything else I can do?

If you don't insist on the toolchain for which you don't have all libraries, you might try to use a different one.
I converted your example from MASM to [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/download/), which uses different names for macros `output`,`input`, `atod`, `dtoa` but they have similar function and are also available online at [winapi.htm](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/winapi.htm), [cpuext32.htm](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/cpuext32.htm)

```
          EUROASM CPU=586
CYBR215   PROGRAM FORMAT=PE,WIDTH=32,MODEL=FLAT,ENTRY=_MainProc
          INCLUDE winapi.htm,cpuext32.htm ; Macroinstruction libraries.

[DATA]    SEGMENT
number1   DD 0 
number2   DD 0
prompt1   DB "Enter First Number ", 0
prompt2   DB "Enter Second Number ", 0
string    DB 40*BYTE 0
resultLb1 DB "The Sum Is ", 0
sum       DB 12*BYTE 0

[CODE]    SEGMENT
_MainProc PROC
    StdOutput prompt1 
    StdInput  string, Size=40     ; read ASCII Characters
    LodD    string                ; convert to integer
    mov     [number1], eax          ; store in memory

    StdOutput prompt2
    StdInput string, Size=40
    LodD    string            ; Load decimal number to EAX as binary.  
    mov     [number2], eax

    mov     eax, [number1]
    add     eax, [number2]
    StoD    sum               ; Store EAX as decimal number to `sum`.
    StdOutput resultLb1, sum
  
    TerminateProgram Errorlevel=0
    ENDP _MainProc
 ENDPROGRAM CYBR215
```

Executable file can be made from the previous source with
`euroasm.exe CYBR215.asm`